# Upload image to my server via PHP using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using the code below to upload image to my server, the code send the request but the response always from the API is (there was an error).

In the same time of uploading the image also some information of this image will be stored in mySql.

Here is my code, I am using Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2

```
 @IBAction func uploadImage(_ sender: Any) {

        self.showActivityIndicator()

        //Post URL
        let url = "https://website.com/folder/include/upload.php"

        //Getting text from textFiled!
        let name = nameField.text!
        let age = ageField.text!

        //Call Parameters
        let params: Parameters = ["name": name,"age": age]

        //Checking image place holder
        let image = UIImage(named: "map.png")

        //Checking if empty name or age fileds
        if name.isEmpty || age.isEmpty{

            self.hideActivityIndicator()
            myAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Make sure you enter all the required information!")
        }

        //Checking if image is not selected!!
        else if imageView.image == image
        {
            self.hideActivityIndicator()
            myAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Make sure you choose an image!")

        }else{

            let imageToUpload = self.imageView.image!

            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:
                {
                    (multipartFormData) in

                    multipartFormData.append(imageToUpload.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)!, withName: "image", fileName: self.generateBoundaryString(), mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    for (key, value) in params
                    {
                        multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
                    }
            }, to:url,headers:nil)
            { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload,_,_ ):
                    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                        //Print progress
                        self.showActivityIndicator()
                    })
                    upload.responseJSON
                        { response in
                            //print response.result
                            if let result = response.result.value {

                                //Calling response from API
                                let message = (result as AnyObject).value(forKey: "message") as! String
                                let status = (result as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as! String

                                //Case Success
                                if status == "1" {

                                    self.hideActivityIndicator()
                                    print("Your Results are ====> ",result)
                                    self.myAlert(title: "Data Upload", msg: message)


                                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "map.png")
                                    self.nameField.text = ""
                                    self.ageField.text = ""

                                }else{
                                    self.hideActivityIndicator()
                                    self.myAlert(title: "Error Uploading", msg: message)
                                }
                            }

                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the PHP file code:

```
<?php

    include 'include/connect.php';

    //Get Param Data
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $xName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name);
    $xAge = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $age);



    //Results Array
    $result = array();

    //Image setup
    $uploads_dir = 'img';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $image_name = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $supported_image = array('gif','jpg','jpeg','png');

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 


    if(empty($xName) || empty($xAge)|| empty($image_name))
    {

        // Send some dummy result back to the iOS app
        $result["message"] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        $result["status"] = "0";
        $result["post"] = $_POST;
        $result["files"] = $_FILES;


    }

    if (! in_array($ext, $supported_image)) 
    {

        // Send some dummy result back to the iOS app
        $result["message"] = "Sorry, Image extension is not Allowed!";
        $result["status"] = "0";
        $result["post"] = $_POST;
        $result["files"] = $_FILES;

    } 
    else
     {

         $query ="INSERT INTO images (name, age, image) VALUES ('$xName', '$xAge','$image_name')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {

            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"$uploads_dir/$image_name");

            // Send some dummy result back to the iOS app
            $result["message"] = "Data has been uploaded successfully.";
            $result["status"] = "1";
            $result["post"] = $_POST;
            $result["files"] = $_FILES;

        }      
     }

    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

The response from the API seems to be missing of some information, but I am filling the two fields with informations needed, which are the (name and age).

I do not what I am missing to complete uploading the image and its informations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this in your button click event--->

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let addPhotos = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: .default) { (addPhoto) in
        self.imgPicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(self.imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera Photo", style: .default) { (CameraPhoto) in
        self.imgPicker.sourceType = .camera
        self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(self.imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let  cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (Cencel) in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alert.addAction(addPhotos)
    alert.addAction(camera)
    alert.addAction(cancel)


    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

then add this function in your code...

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let  img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{

```
        self.imgProfileImage.image = img

        let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5)!

        let parameters = [String : Any]

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "Folder Name",fileName: "PicName.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
            } //Optional for extra parameters
        },
                         to:"Your API is Here.")
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.result.value)
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }

    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```